# Format of PostgreSQL trigger exception text depend on system?

Tags: django, postgresql

I wrote a trigger on insert event for PostgreSQL, which raise exception on some circumstances. This is piece of pg_plsql code (which raise exception):

```
IF user_rating.user_id = NEW.user1_id THEN
    CASE error_id
    WHEN 0 THEN creator_allow_flag := True;
    WHEN 1,2 THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'error|creator|%', available_limit;
    END CASE;
ELSIF user_rating.user_id = NEW.user2_id THEN
    CASE error_id
    WHEN 0 THEN partner_allow_flag := True;
    WHEN 1,2 THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'error|partner|%', available_limit;
    END CASE;
ELSE
    RAISE EXCEPTION '%', user_rating.user_id;
END IF;
```

Django app based on user action generates INSERT SQL command, which causes my pl_pgsql trigger and catch the exception of type InternalError (from django.db) if trigger raise exception. And text of exceptions passed to my django app as attribute of Django Exception object.

It's work fine, but on different systems differ text of exception, which return from PostgreSQL.

On system with configuration:

- Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
- Package: postgresql 9.3
- Version: 9.3.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

Output look like 'error|creator|7.56111'.

But on system with configuration:

- Debian 7.7 Stable
- Package: postgresql-9.3
- Version: 9.3.5-1.pgdg70+1

Output look like 'ОШИБКА: error|creator|7.56111' (system locale is russian).

Why does this happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL reports errors translated into the locale of the database. If you don't want that you can change `LC_MESSAGES` at `CREATE DATABASE` time (or possibly with `ALTER DATABASE`, I haven't checked).

However, you shouldn't be parsing error messages. Use the extended error message structure - [accessible via `psycopg2.extensions.Diagnostics`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.Diagnostics). Use one of the `RAISE` forms that lets you specify a `DETAIL` message and store your app payload in there, and use a custom `SQLSTATE` to indicate to your app that it's an application specific message with payload in detail.

PostgreSQL may (and has, in the past) change error message formats. Don't rely on being able to parse them.

Comment: Great thanks for the good advice. For posterity: In Django case - psycopg2 exception object is located in __cause__ property of django.db exception object (in my case - django.db.InternalError.__cause__).